# Adjunction Formula

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves

- **Theorem** :

For $ X $ a smooth variety ( or complex manifold ), and $ Y \subseteq X $ of codimension $ 1 $, then :
$$ K_Y = (K_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X (Y))_{|Y} $$

- **Questions** :

$ 1) $ What is the meaning of $ \mathcal{O}_X (Y) $ in the formula : $ K_Y = (K_X \otimes \mathcal{O}_X (Y))_{|Y} $ ?

$ 2) $ Suppose $ X \subseteq \mathbb{P}^2 $ is a smooth curve of degree $ d $. Why is : $ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{2} } (X) = \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^{n}} (d) $ ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_X(-Y)$ is the ideal sheaf of functions vanishing on $Y$. This is a line bundle and its dual is $\mathcal{O}_X(Y)$. This should answer your second question too.

Comment: Thank you, but, i still not understand why $ \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } ( -X) = \mathcal{O}_{ \mathbb{P}^{n} } ( -d ) $. Can you tell me why please ?

Comment: More or less by definition, a smooth curve of degree d in the plane is given by a degree d homogenous polynomial in 3 variables say $h$. A meromorphic function with poles along $X$ is simply given by $f/h$ where $f$ is homogenous of degre d, and thus the corresponding sheaf is isomorphic to $O(d)$. Thus $O(X)\simeq O(d)$ and dually you have $O(-X)\simeq O(-d)$.

Comment: @A.Rod : Thank you. Just a small question : Is $ O(d) $ the sheaf corresponding to meromorphic function $ f/h $ where $ f $ and $ g $ are homogeneous of degree $ d $ ? Where can i find this definition of $ O(d) $ ?

Comment: $\mathcal O(d)$ is the sheaf of functions on the form $f/g$ with $\text{deg}(f) - \text{deg}(g) = d$. I think Gathman uses this definition in his notes on algebraic geometry.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas, but i still not understand the comment of @A.Rod above. If we follow what A.Rod has said, $ O(X) $ is isomorphic to $ O(d) $ by the isomorphism : $ \phi_U : O(X)(U) \to O(d)(U) $ defined by : $ \phi_U \big( \dfrac{f_{U}}{h_{U}} \big) = f_U $, no ?